# React Layout VS Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have question about displaying or routing components in React.
I've set a main page `Layout` with a `Header`, a `Left` menu, and a `Content` part. The idea is to have one single page where you only change the main content part.
I would like to know if it is a good approach or not and if I have to do this with router or just with hook.

In what I've done I just use a `useState` hook to set the component to display and router is not necessary but I wonder if it's the correct way or not.

- On menu click:

  ```
  setContent(<QueryIndicators />)
  ```
- I have a `Content` part displaying the current component:

  `<Content className="layout__content">{content}</Content>`

  ```
  const Login = () => {
    const REACT_VERSION = React.version

    const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true)
    const [content, setContent] = useState(<QueryIndicators />)

    return (
      <Layout className="layout">
        <Sider
          className="layout__sider"
          collapsible
          collapsed={collapsed}
          onCollapse={value => setCollapsed(value)}
        >
          <Menu
            mode="inline"
            defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
            className="layout__sider-menu"
          >
            <Menu.Item
              key="1"
              icon={<HomeTwoTone twoToneColor={'#184287'} />}
              onClick={() => setContent(<QueryIndicators />)}
            >
              Home
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item
              key="2"
              icon={<PlayCircleOutlined />}
              onClick={() => setContent(<QueryExecutor />)}
            >
              Executor
            </Menu.Item >          
          </Menu>
        </Sider>

        <Layout>
          <Header className="layout__header">
            {React.createElement(
              collapsed ? MenuUnfoldOutlined : MenuFoldOutlined,
              {
                className: 'trigger',
                onClick: () => setCollapsed(!collapsed)
              }
            )}
            <h1
              className="layout__header-text"
              title={'React:' + REACT_VERSION}
            >
              POA Console HOME
            </h1>
          </Header>
          <Content className="layout__content">{content}</Content>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    )
  }

  export default Login
  ```

Comment: It all depends on your usecase and size of your application. Router is not just only for static routes, you can also have dynamic routes and in that scenarios you can get the dynamic values using the router hooks. You can maintain the routes with either `useState` or Context api but it will become troublesome as your app grows bigger.

Answer (score 0):

It's subjective *how* you want to apply conditional logic to display/render content based on user interaction, but you've multiple options.

### Using local state

Using the local state seems fine, though I will warn you that it's considered a React anti-pattern to store JSX in state, store some data (*e.g. a reference to the component*) and map this state to the JSX you want rendered.

Example:

```
const QUERY_CONTENT = {
  QueryExecutor,
  QueryIndicators,
}

const Login = () => {
  const REACT_VERSION = React.version;

  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);
  const [QueryContent, setQueryContent] = useState(QUERY_CONTENT.QueryIndicators);

  return (
    <Layout className="layout">
      <Sider
        className="layout__sider"
        collapsible
        collapsed={collapsed}
        onCollapse={value => setCollapsed(value)}
      >
        <Menu
          mode="inline"
          defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
          className="layout__sider-menu"
        >
          <Menu.Item
            key="1"
            icon={<HomeTwoTone twoToneColor={'#184287'} />}
            onClick={() => setQueryContent(QUERY_CONTENT.QueryIndicators)}
          >
            Home
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item
            key="2"
            icon={<PlayCircleOutlined />}
            onClick={() => setQueryContent(QUERY_CONTENT.QueryExecutor)}
          >
            Executor
          </Menu.Item >          
        </Menu>
      </Sider>

      <Layout>
        <Header className="layout__header">
          {React.createElement(
            collapsed ? MenuUnfoldOutlined : MenuFoldOutlined,
            {
              className: 'trigger',
              onClick: () => setCollapsed(collapsed => !collapsed)
            }
          )}
          <h1
            className="layout__header-text"
            title={'React:' + REACT_VERSION}
          >
            POA Console HOME
          </h1>
        </Header>
        <Content className="layout__content">
          <QueryContent />
        </Content>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

### Using routes

If you are wanting to use `react-router` and routes to manage the conditional rendering of content then convert the component into a layout component that renders an `Outlet` component for nested routes to be rendered into. The router/routes will manage route matching and rendering the specific routed content.

Example:

```
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const REACT_VERSION = React.version;

const AppLayout = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);

  return (
    <Layout className="layout">
      <Sider
        className="layout__sider"
        collapsible
        collapsed={collapsed}
        onCollapse={setCollapsed}
      >
        <Menu
          mode="inline"
          defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
          className="layout__sider-menu"
        >
          <Menu.Item
            key="1"
            icon={<HomeTwoTone twoToneColor={'#184287'} />}
            onClick={() => navigate("/queryIndicators")}
          >
            Home
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item
            key="2"
            icon={<PlayCircleOutlined />}
            onClick={() => navigate("/queryExecutor")}
          >
            Executor
          </Menu.Item >          
        </Menu>
      </Sider>

      <Layout>
        <Header className="layout__header">
          {React.createElement(
            collapsed ? MenuUnfoldOutlined : MenuFoldOutlined,
            {
              className: 'trigger',
              onClick: () => setCollapsed(collapsed => !collapsed)
            }
          )}
          <h1
            className="layout__header-text"
            title={'React:' + REACT_VERSION}
          >
            POA Console HOME
          </h1>
        </Header>
        <Content className="layout__content">
          <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render here
        </Content>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  ...

  return (
    ...
    <Routes>
      ...
      <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
        ...
        <Route path="/queryIndicators" element={<QueryIndicators />} />
        <Route path="/queryExecutor" element={<QueryExecutor />} />
        ...
      </Route>
      ...
    </Routes>
    ...
  );
};
```

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```

Comment: Tanks for your response it's really interesting.
So if using state to manipulate content to render components is not really a good practice, how can I do it to have a main layout page in which I change only the désired content, according the component I need to render ?

Comment: @Anthony The bad practice is storing the JSX in state. You can use state to store data or the value or whatever the conditional rendering is based on just fine. Can you clarify the rest of your comment though, what you mean?

Comment: I was wondering hot to have a global page Layout with a "central" content part displaying  a selected component but with routes, instead of the useState I've set

Comment: @Anthony Sorry, went on vacation last week. I've updated my answer with a solution using routing to conditionally render content. Please do check it out when you've time.